# How to properly group items in a string?

Tags: python, string, list

I currently have a group of strings that look like this:

```
[58729 58708]

[58729]

[58708]

[58729]
```

I need to turn them into a list, but when I use list(), I get:

```
['[', '5', '8', '7', '2', '9', ']']

['[', '5', '8', '7', '0', '8', ']']

['[', '5', '8', '7', '2', '9', ']']

['[', '5', '8', '7', '2', '9', ' ', '5', '8', '7', '0', '8', ']']
```

How do I group them so that they don't get separated out into individual characters? So, something like this:

```
['58729', '58708']

['58729']

['58708']

['58729']
```

Comment: `'[58729 58708]'[1:-1].split()`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your input string is assigned to a variable foo.

```
foo = '[58729 58708]'
```

First, you want to use list slicing to get rid of the brackets at the start and end of the string:

```
foo = foo[1:-1]
```

Now, you can just use the string method split() to turn the string into a list. Here, the input of split() is the character at which the list shall be split. In your case, that would be a single space character:

```
foo.split(' ')
```

This returns

```
['58729', '58708'].
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with "ast" module usage

```
import ast

data_str = '[58729 58708]'

data_str = data_str.replace(' ',',')  # make it '[58729, 58708]'

x = ast.literal_eval(data_str)


print(x)  
Out[1]:
    [58729, 58708]

print(x[0])
Out[2]:
    58729

print(type(x))
Out[3]:
    <class 'list'>

# and after all if you want exactly list of string:
[str(s) for s in x]
Out[4]:
    ['58729', '58708']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regex** to extract the values between the square brackets, then `split` the values into a list.

#### The code:

```
import re

s = '[58729 58708]'
result = re.search('\[(.*)\]', s).group(1).split()
```

#### The result:

```
>>> %Run string2list.py
['58729', '58708']

>>> %Run string2list.py
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Imo the royal path would be to combine a regex with a small parser:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor
import re

data = """
[58729 58708]

[58729]

[58708]

[58729]
"""

# outer expression
rx = re.compile(r'\[[^\[\]]+\]')

# nodevisitor class
class StringVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    grammar = Grammar(
        r"""
        list    = lpar content+ rpar
        content = item ws?
        item    = ~"[^\[\]\s]+"
        ws      = ~"\s+"
        lpar    = "["
        rpar    = "]"
        """
    )

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_content(self, node, visited_children):
        item, _ = visited_children
        return item.text

    def visit_list(self, node, visited_children):
        _, content, _ = visited_children
        return [item for item in content]


sv = StringVisitor()
for lst in rx.finditer(data):
    real_list = sv.parse(lst.group(0))
    print(real_list)
```

Which would yield

```
['58729', '58708']
['58729']
['58708']
['58729']
```